# Movie Clips inside of buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, button, movieclip, flash-cs6

I am using AS 3.0 and I have a button (mcbtn1) with a movie clip inside that has a animation when you hover over plays the animation and stops and then another button that I want to go to scene 2

```
function gotoCenter(event:MouseEvent):void {
MovieClip(root).btn_K.gotoAndStop(1, "Scene");
}
mcbtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoCenter);
```

this is the code I am using

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Consider rephrasing your question to clarify what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're getting an error accessing the movieclip inside that button.
It is not applicable to put movieclips inside buttons. The best solution is to use movieclip(as replacement to your button). Then, you might use yourMovieClip.buttonMode = true
to access button properties.